# Get data from a multi dimensional in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a private function

```
private $_CODES = array(
    301 => array(
        "code"=> 301,
        "message"=> "User With ID Not Found",
        "type"=> "Error"
    ),
    302 => array(
        "code"=> 302,
        "message"=> "Email Id Not Valid",
        "type"=> "Error"
    ),
);
```

Accessing this function using a public function getError both function are in the same class.

```
public  function getError($code)
    {   
        return $this->_CODES[]=$code;
    }
```

I am getting the error code only, means 301 am not getting the exact message. while passing the parameter($code) need to get corresponding error message. what I was missed here? 
i have called the error function like this

```
       echo json_encode(Errors::getError(301));
```

Comment: "I have a private function" - it's not a function, it's a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why it doesn't work

```
return $this->_CODES[]=$code;
```

That code appends `$code` to the `$this->_CODES` array and then returns the result of that assignment, which is `$code` itself.

For example:

```
$array = array();
echo $array[] = 123; // "123"
print_r($array); // Array(123)
```

See also: [Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

#### What will work

You will want to use array dereferencing like this:

```
return $this->_CODES[$code]['message']; // return just the message
```

Or:

```
return $this->_CODES[$code]; // returns all three fields as a new array
```

See also: [Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)

#### Update

If you want `Errors::getError(301)` to work, you need to declare your function and array as static, i.e.:

```
class Errors
    private static $_CODES = array(
        301 => array(
          "code"=> 301, 
          "message"=> "User With ID Not Found", 
          "type"=> "Error"
        )
    ); 

    public static function getError($code) { 
        return self::$_CODES[$code]['message'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Naveen Oh, I totally didn't get that at first, you need to declare your method statically.

Comment: @Naveen You're welcome, could you help me clean up the comments section of this answer? :)

Comment: Working Perfect Thanks Jack

Answer (score 3):

```
public  function getError($code)
    {   
        return $this->_CODES[$code]['message'];
    }
```

Comment: Then what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Naveen well, it does

Comment: @Naveen pls, upvote all you've downvoted
`class Error {
    private static $_CODES = array(
        301 => array(
            "code"=> 301,
            "message"=> "User With ID Not Found",
            "type"=> "Error"
        ),
        302 => array(
            "code"=> 302,
            "message"=> "Email Id Not Valid",
            "type"=> "Error"
        ),
    );

    public static function getError($code)
    {
        return self::$_CODES[$code]['message'];
    }
}`